# Problems with Non English characters which exporting SQL table to a CSV file

Tags: c#, sql, unicode, export-to-csv

I have a table in SQL that stores Twitter data. It has language set from Japanese, Arabic etc.

When that table is exported to CSV using a C# code, the Non English alphabets are not handled correctly and they appear in a weird format

Ex. 東京都品川区大崎 gets written as æ±äº¬éƒ½å“å·åŒºå¤§å´Ž

Is there anything I can do in my code or in CSV to avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does it look normal in sql or is it just when you transfer from SQL to csv? if its gibberish in sql try changing the sql column to ntext

Comment: It is fine in SQL. problem when i change it to csv

Answer (score 0):

Use UTF 8 encoding,something like

```
new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8)
```